# React Routing does not work in Routers but renders fine outside of Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to build a personal resume website but react router is not rendering when I call my components in my `App.js` routes. The component renders fine when I call it above my routes but I do not want it to be displayed to all my pages, I just want it to be rendered to the home route. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

`Home.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../App.css';
import HeroSection from '../HeroSection';

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HeroSection />
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css'; 
import NavBar from './Components/NavBar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'; 
import Home from './Components/pages/Home';
import Projects from './Components/pages/Projects';
function App() {
  return (
   
    
    <Router>
      {/* put anything that should be displayed to all pages */}
      <NavBar/>
      <Home/> {/*works fine here*/}
      <Routes>
          <Route  exact path= './' component={Home}/> 
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`package.json`

```
    {
  "name": "myresume",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show your package.json please,

Comment: I added my package.json file

Comment: why the dot in the path `path= './'`? Remove the dot so its like `path= '/'` and you will be able to access it

Comment: can you be more specific on what you are looking to do? For instance: what component do you `not` want to show? To me it looks like you have a `Navbar` component on every page and your `root route` is the `home` page. 

Just as a side note, you can leave your path as `/` rather than `./`

Comment: took it of but still same issue

Comment: @pythonNovice I am looking to render home just for the home page, but it does not render when in routes. It is rendering fine when I do not include it in routes and just call it like <Home/> above the routes in App.js, IDK why its not rendering in Routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below method instead?

```js
import Home from './Components/pages/Home';

function App() {
  return (
   
    
    <Router>
      <NavBar/>
      <Routes>
          <Route  exact path= '/' element={<Home/>}/>  // replace component with element
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I'm basing my answer off of this  since you are using version 6 of react router dom https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

Answer (score 3):

Your using react-router-dom version 6!

Thats NOT how you do it in version 6. Read the docs!

It should be `element={<Home />}` not `component={Home}`

You can see the bascis here https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview

On how to upgrade from v5 to v6: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

Comment: still same issue with . removed. Thank you for your reply

Comment: I have edit my answer. Can you try it?